# Is it possible to bookmark a Blazor page?

Tags: blazor, webassembly, bookmarks

I have an IIS website at localhost that serves up a Blazor WASM app.  When the users goes to localhost, they are redirected to localhost/login.  This works fine, but I've been told that some users are bookmarking the page at localhost/login, but this bookmark doesn't work. When you attempt to use it, a 404 error occurs. Is there any way to handle this problem and still allow a user to use a bookmark?

Comment: Honoring bookmarks is precisely how it works out of the box with the default project template.  Also note, bookmarks are no different than simply entering the URL in the address bar.  Are you saying that you can or cannot access that `/login` path when you just enter it into the browser's address bar?

Comment: The default Blazor WASM app does not contain a routable component (page) named Login, and you most certainly did not create one. You're probably  referring to Login.cshtml. You can't and you should not bookmark it. It is created as a result of redirection from Blazor.